# Export to Excel Pdf is not working in Datatable after select option filter in php ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have multiple select option filtering based on ajax jquery php in datatable. It is filtering the records correctly but after change on select option  filtering is done but Export to Excel Pdf is not working

**Note:-**

(1)It always download 10 records in excel & pdf.

(2)Count below the datatable is not showing correctly.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.select_filter').on('change',function(){
       
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "ajaxCompany_search.php",
           data: $('#search_form').serialize(), // You will get all the select data..
            success:function(data){
             var data = $(data);
               alert(data);
         datatable.clear().rows.add(data).draw();
               $("#projects").html(data);

            }
        });
  });
  });


     var datatable = $('#example').DataTable({
dom: 'Bfrtip',
buttons: [
  'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
]
  });
```

```css
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></link>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"></link>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-md-12">
<form name="search_form" id="search_form" method="POST"> 
          
 <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="formrow">
                  <select class="form-control select_filter" name="job_title" >
                    <option value ='' disabled selected>Job Title</option>
                    <option>PHP Developer</option>
                    <option>Android Developer</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              
  <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="formrow">
                  <select class="form-control select_filter" name="emp_status" >
                    <option value ='' disabled selected>Employment Status</option>
                    <option>Permanant</option>
                    <option>Contract</option>
                    <option>Freelance</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              
                      
          
         
     <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="formrow">
                  <select class="form-control select_filter" name="experience" >
                    <option value ='' disabled selected>Experience</option>
                    <option>Fresher</option>
                    <option>1 Year</option>
                    <option>2 Years</option>
                    <option>3 Years</option>
                    <option>4 Years</option>
                    <option>5 Years</option>
                    <option>6 Years</option>
                    <option>7 Years</option>
                    <option>8 Years</option>
                    <option>9 Years</option>
                    <option>10 Years</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
</form>
 </div>


        
    
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="box box-danger">
            <div class="box-body table-responsive">
              <table id="example" class="table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>S.No</th>
                  <th>Company name</th>
                 <th>Company email</th>
                  <th>Company mobile</th>
                    <th>Company address</th>
                     <th>Job title</th>
                      <th>Industry</th>
                       <th>Salary</th>
                        <th>Employment Type</th>
                         <th>No. Of Positions</th>
                          <th>Experience</th>
                     <th>Job Description</th>
                 <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="projects">
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

**ajaxCompany_search.php**

```
<?php
include('../../config.php');
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are directly appending new rows inside your table so only `tbody` datas are updated not datatable plugin itself . Instead you can `clear` your datatable and then draw it again using `draw()` method.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var datatable = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
  });
  $('.select_filter').on('change', function() {
    /*$.ajax({
         
          success: function(data) {*/
    //use object arround your html adding around `$()`
    var data = $('<tr><td>Row 1 Data 1</td><td>Row 1 Data 2</td></tr>')
    //clear datatble an add new datas 
    datatable.clear().rows.add(data).draw();

    /* }
    });*/
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select_filter" name="emptype">
  <option value='' disabled selected>Employment Status</option>
  <option>Permanent</option>
  <option>Contract</option>
  <option>Freelance</option>
</select>
<table id="example">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody id="projects">
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: mam my `success:function(data)` is coming `dynamically` then what i do??

Comment: `data` is html code ? If yes just put `$()` around that i.e : `$(data)` and then put it inside your table like above .

Comment: Like this : `datatable.clear().rows.add($(data)).draw();` see if that works .

Comment: i write `var data = $(data);datatable.clear().rows.add($(data)).draw();$("#projects").html(data);` after `success:function` but it does not filter records.

Comment: no not like that you just need to write `datatable.clear().rows.add($(data)).draw();`  remove this `var data = $(data);` and `$("#projects").html(data);` lines and make sure `datatable` is intialize like i have did in above demo code .

Comment: mam i tried all the ways but did not filter records .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228584/discussion-between-swati-and-kumar).